# Shibboleth restful api

Tags: restful-authentication, cas, shibboleth

I am writing an android application for an University that uses Shibboleth for authenticating the students.

Since I am making a android native app (not a webview), I would like to programmatically pass the username and password and get back the user credentials of the user. Does Shibboleth have a restful api that I can use.

for ex. CAS has https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/RESTful+API which would allow me to programmatically send a username and password and get back the ticket credentials. Is there something similar for shibboleth?

Answer (score 5):

Shibboleth does not provide a REST interface, but they do have a non-browser-oriented authentication profile called ECP.
https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/CONCEPT/ECP

Answer (score 1):

Shibboleth doesn't have any restful support. However you can still use JAAS + Java plugin + Rest client to do authentication by calling your Restful based  authentication system. I had similar implementation

Comment: Can you please share some link using which I can authenticate without using webflow or Ecp flow ? I mean by implementing rest api.